# how can i stop my gradle from causing this error?

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code

just starting java programming and when ever i start visual studio code gradle says it cant start gradle language server as seen in this picture:

[image: this is what shows up]

it also throws out alot of horrible errors :

```
Oct 15, 2021 9:51:13 PM org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.RemoteEndpoint fallbackResponseError
SEVERE: Internal error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.services.GenericEndpoint.lambda$null$0(GenericEndpoint.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.services.GenericEndpoint.request(GenericEndpoint.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.RemoteEndpoint.handleRequest(RemoteEndpoint.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.RemoteEndpoint.consume(RemoteEndpoint.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.StreamMessageProducer.handleMessage(StreamMessageProducer.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.StreamMessageProducer.listen(StreamMessageProducer.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.ConcurrentMessageProcessor.run(ConcurrentMessageProcessor.java:113)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.services.GenericEndpoint.lambda$null$0(GenericEndpoint.java:65)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "<local3>" is null
    at com.microsoft.gradle.resolver.GradleLibraryResolver.searchInFolder(GradleLibraryResolver.java:161)
    at com.microsoft.gradle.resolver.GradleLibraryResolver.findCoreAPIWithDist(GradleLibraryResolver.java:152)
    at com.microsoft.gradle.resolver.GradleLibraryResolver.findCoreAPIWithWrapper(GradleLibraryResolver.java:140)
    at com.microsoft.gradle.resolver.GradleLibraryResolver.resolveGradleAPI(GradleLibraryResolver.java:89)
    at com.microsoft.gradle.GradleServices.applySetting(GradleServices.java:160)
    at com.microsoft.gradle.GradleLanguageServer.initialize(GradleLanguageServer.java:90)
    ... 16 more

[Error - 21:51:14] Server initialization failed.
  Message: Internal error.
  Code: -32603 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.services.GenericEndpoint.lambda$null$0(GenericEndpoint.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.services.GenericEndpoint.request(GenericEndpoint.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.RemoteEndpoint.handleRequest(RemoteEndpoint.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.RemoteEndpoint.consume(RemoteEndpoint.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.StreamMessageProducer.handleMessage(StreamMessageProducer.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.StreamMessageProducer.listen(StreamMessageProducer.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.ConcurrentMessageProcessor.run(ConcurrentMessageProcessor.java:113)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.services.GenericEndpoint.lambda$null$0(GenericEndpoint.java:65)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "<local3>" is null
    at com.microsoft.gradle.resolver.GradleLibraryResolver.searchInFolder(GradleLibraryResolver.java:161)
    at com.microsoft.gradle.resolver.GradleLibraryResolver.findCoreAPIWithDist(GradleLibraryResolver.java:152)
    at com.microsoft.gradle.resolver.GradleLibraryResolver.findCoreAPIWithWrapper(GradleLibraryResolver.java:140)
    at com.microsoft.gradle.resolver.GradleLibraryResolver.resolveGradleAPI(GradleLibraryResolver.java:89)
    at com.microsoft.gradle.GradleServices.applySetting(GradleServices.java:160)
    at com.microsoft.gradle.GradleLanguageServer.initialize(GradleLanguageServer.java:90)
    ... 16 more

[Error - 21:51:14] Starting client failed
  Message: Internal error.
  Code: -32603 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.services.GenericEndpoint.lambda$null$0(GenericEndpoint.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.services.GenericEndpoint.request(GenericEndpoint.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.RemoteEndpoint.handleRequest(RemoteEndpoint.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.RemoteEndpoint.consume(RemoteEndpoint.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.StreamMessageProducer.handleMessage(StreamMessageProducer.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.StreamMessageProducer.listen(StreamMessageProducer.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.ConcurrentMessageProcessor.run(ConcurrentMessageProcessor.java:113)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.services.GenericEndpoint.lambda$null$0(GenericEndpoint.java:65)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "<local3>" is null
    at com.microsoft.gradle.resolver.GradleLibraryResolver.searchInFolder(GradleLibraryResolver.java:161)
    at com.microsoft.gradle.resolver.GradleLibraryResolver.findCoreAPIWithDist(GradleLibraryResolver.java:152)
    at com.microsoft.gradle.resolver.GradleLibraryResolver.findCoreAPIWithWrapper(GradleLibraryResolver.java:140)
    at com.microsoft.gradle.resolver.GradleLibraryResolver.resolveGradleAPI(GradleLibraryResolver.java:89)
    at com.microsoft.gradle.GradleServices.applySetting(GradleServices.java:160)
    at com.microsoft.gradle.GradleLanguageServer.initialize(GradleLanguageServer.java:90)
    ... 16 more
```

i have tried everything i can think of to try and fix this but nothing seems to work any help would really be appriciated,
thank you in advanced

Comment: Maybe try running/reinstalling gradle through the [official gradle installation guide](https://gradle.org/install/)?

Comment: i have tried this but no diffrence when runnign vscode

Comment: Notice the error `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "<local3>" is null`. Fix it then see if question goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know squat about Visual Studio, but you probably have to configure it for Gradle. Googling around speaks of a VS "Plug In" to get "Gradle Language Support". Do you have that plug-in? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=naco-siren.gradle-language

The other thing I always do with gradle projects is to get them to build from the commandline first, then figure out how to get them into the IDE.

Most "modern", or maybe more recent might be a better term, have "the gradle wrapper" installed. From a command line you usually only need to `./gradlew build` on Unix, `gradlew.bat build` on Windows.

Comment: i have tried all three of these and i havent noticed a diffrence how ever ./gradlew build doesnt work as ./gradlew isnt a reconised command maybe that has something to do with it

Comment: @connorb151, gradlew and gradlew.bat are files. If the project has gone through the "gradle wrapper", you would just find them with `ls` for unix, or `dir` on windows. It looks like you are out of luck here. Sorry I'm of little help. For Java, I love gradle as a build tool.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I connected  to an internet connection and run vs code. The gradle files might be attempting to update…

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).